# Winforms DotNet ListBox items to word wrap if content string width is bigger than ListBox width?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, width, listboxitem

Ehm, umm, this means some lines should be two-lined in size. My boss think this is more simple solution, than limit displayed text to fit width and don't like horizontal scroll bar >_<

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
lst.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
lst.MeasureItem += lst_MeasureItem;
lst.DrawItem += lst_DrawItem;

private void lst_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(lst.Items[e.Index].ToString(), lst.Font, lst.Width).Height;
}

private void lst_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lst.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
}
```

Comment: Love it. One minor thing though. When I databind a custom class, the DisplayMember gets wiped and I can't seem to reset it. Any tips?

Comment: @BillSambrone - Sorry, but I don't use databind and never meet same problem and don't know how to solve.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt : totaly agree

Comment: @Kosmos Seems that the `ListBox` caches the items height, what is good. The problem is that if the `ListBox` is resized it don't recalculates the height! I'm trying someway to clean the cache of items height without removing and adding then, in the `resize`, but I don't find any method for that. At least documented.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento - I used `ListBox.Refresh` method in `resize` handler for that.

Comment: @Kosmos `Refresh` does not work, it will just add all the area of the `ListBox` to next `Paint` event, but does not calculate the new items height.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento - I don't know why, but for me it worked fine. I used Form's resize event and called list box's Refresh method. I don't know why you telling it's not working. Refresh causes control to redraw and when it redraws it should run the calculation code again.

Comment: @Kosmos what version of .Net are you using (even trough the `ListBox` is a native windows control)? It don't raise the `MeasureItem` event, you can search for the same question in other places. Anyway I found [a way to change item height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490543/windows-forms-listbox-with-ownerdrawvariable-bug)

Comment: Also take a look at that **Unfortunately, the MeasureItem event only happens when the handle gets created** in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072539/expanding-selected-item-height-in-listbox/7072554).

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento - Meh, I tested it and finally understand what you meant. I though that text stays the same after resizing (no updates), but the text changes according to space available, while item height no. Well..., currently I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Kosmos Yes, that's it. Putting it, the item height is dependent on the item width, being the item width dependent on the control client area width. I come [with a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490543/windows-forms-listbox-with-ownerdrawvariable-bug). The `ListBox` that is a native windows control, has way to set item height, so you can call it with "Windows API". Also, I make a call to the measure item, for each item and called the "Windows API", so that it worked. There's only a glitch when the scroll bar gets show or hidden. Thanks!

Comment: @BillSambrone If you use a custom class, you need to replace "lst.Items[e.Index].ToString()" to "((CustomClass)lst.Items[e.Index]).YourMethodShowTheClass".

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void lst_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(lst.Items[e.Index].ToString(), lst.Font, lst.Width).Height;
}

private void lst_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lst.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
}
```

To get the right display member to show up when data binding, replace

```
lst.Items[e.Index].ToString()
```

with a casted version of the property.  So if your binding source is class object Car it would look like

```
((Car)lst.Items[e.Index]).YourDisplayProperty
```

Then the above functions can appropriately measure the string and draw it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

[Helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397257/force-textblock-to-wrap-in-wpf-listbox)

Check out this answer. It overrides the template of the listbox with a textblock which wraps the text. Hope it's useful. To solve your problem I think you shold add : ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" . Found it  [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/wpf-and-wordwrap-wordtrimming-in-a-listb)

Comment: Thanks, but I use win forms :(

Answer (score 0):

To make binding correct, be sure to add check "lst.Items.Count > 0" to lst_MeasureItem function. Here is my example:

```
 if (lst.Items.Count > 0)
 {
    e.ItemHeight = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(lst.Items[e.Index].ToString(), lst.Font, lst.Width).Height;
 }
```

Everything else seems to work nicely after that.