# content in listbox exceed the width

Tags: c#, listbox, width, exceed

I have a listbox with a bunch of different strings, added by a button. Some of these strings are too long for the listbox, so the end of the strings exceed the width of the listbox. Now, I know I could just make the listbox longer, but that seems too easy.

There must be a function that somehow breaks the string at an appropriate length so that I can see the whole string in the listbox, but now, for example, at two rows, instead of one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613613/are-there-anyway-to-make-listbox-items-to-word-wrap-if-string-width-is-higher-th
Does that help?

Comment: That helped! The code looks a little bit complicated but works great!