# How can I wrap the text in a ListBox?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, text, listbox

I am populating a `ListBox` with the current function:

```
Public Function fillListBox5(theList As List(Of FARG_Data))
    For Each item In theList
        ListBox5.Items.Add(item.getFargFunction)
    Next
End Function
```

This works well, but some of the item's `FargFunctions` are decently long causing portions of the string to be cut off at the end of the `ListBox`. Is there anyway I can make the text wrap so that none of it is cut off?

Comment: Its not cut off as in truncated, it just isnt showing.  If you want it to wrap, you are probably going to have to make it OwnerDraw and paint them yourself.  You also do not need to copy the data to the control one by one - just use the List as a DataSource: `ListBox52,DataSource = theList`

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613613/winforms-dotnet-listbox-items-to-word-wrap-if-content-string-width-is-bigger-tha

Comment: @PrescottChartier Thanks for pointing me to that question, weird title... must have been why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [ListBox.HorizontalScrollbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.horizontalscrollbar(v=vs.110).aspx) property to **True**. This can either be done within the designer or programmatically:

```
ListBox5.HorizontalScrollbar = True
```

This will give the user the ability to scroll and view all the text:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Or you can set the css style `overflow: auto;`

```
select {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: The answer you gave is only applicable in HTML whereas the asked question targetted Winforms