# How can i say that when the listbox row is full it continues with the next line

Tags: c#, listbox

So I want to put information from my database into a listbox. But the problem is that the listbox does not care about how long the informations are. And I want that the listbox see if the listbox has not place it continues with the next line

Comment: You want long lines of text to word wrap?

Comment: you can try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17640123/6170890