# Windows.Forms.ListBox with OwnerDrawVariable bug?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

In a `Windows.Forms.ListBox` with the property `DrawMode` set to `OwnerDrawVariable`, the `ListBox` seems to cache the height of the items, what is good.

BUT, being the item height dependent of the width, because it uses `Graphics.MeasureString` to do word wrap, needs to calculate the height of items if the size of the `ListBox` has changed. Then there's a problem.

The `ListBox` doesn't do this by default, and I can't find a method to clear the cache, forcing the `ListBox` to raise the itemheight event.

Any solution? I tried to get the source for the ListBox but don't find anything about that to make a derived class and clear this cache.

(Tried copying the items to an array, clearing the `ListBox.Items`, and tem adding the array again. This even throw exceptions as the `ListBox` calling the drawitem or itemheight events with invalid item index)

Comment: See [Expanding Selected Item height in ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7072554/719186)

Comment: @HansPassant drawing functions, like `Invalidade`, `Refresh` and `Update` does not make it, will be easy if so.

Comment: @LarsTech thanks, *Unfortunately, the MeasureItem event only happens when the handle gets created* is very frustrating.

Comment: @LarsTech `RecreateHandle()` seems a bit overhead to that, as I don't find anything about item height in the source code (but its a older one), this should be done at non-managed code? If you want, post your word-around as an answer.

Comment: You could remove the item and insert it back.  That triggers a measure.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) window message for the native ListBox control.

Comment: @HansPassant that was already tried as explained in the question. But I removed and re-inserted all the items. Seems the most inefficient way, but even that, it gives index errors, maybe removing and adding one by one will not cause this errors, but a resize operating will need to remove and insert all items (unless some calculation is made before), what causes a big overhead as the control will redraw itself at each remove and insert operation.

Answer (score 1):

According [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN

> **LB_SETITEMHEIGHT message**
>
> Sets the height, in pixels, of items in a list box. If the list box has the
>   **LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE** style, this message sets the height of the item
>   specified by the wParam parameter. Otherwise, this message sets the height
>   of all items in the list box.

So this will do it

```
private const int LB_SETITEMHEIGHT = 0x01A0;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private void ListBoxExample_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ListBoxExample.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        MeasureItemEventArgs eArgs = new MeasureItemEventArgs(null, i);
        ListBoxExample_MeasureItem((object)ListBoxExample, eArgs);
        SendMessage((IntPtr) ListBoxExample.Handle, LB_SETITEMHEIGHT, (IntPtr) i, (IntPtr) e.ItemHeight);
    }
}
```

The `MeasureItemEventArgs` accepts a `Graphics` object, if necessary, create one from the control and pass it in the first argument.